# Redirect to a specific page after successful action - Redux saga

Tags: reactjs, redux-saga

I have a user profile page where the user can update the data. Once the data is submitted, it should be redirected to dashboard page.

MyProfile.js

```
  handleProfileUpdate = () => {
    let user = this.state;
    this.props.updateUserProfile(user);
  }
```

Action is defined as follows

```
export const updateUserProfile = (obj) => ({
  type: types.USER_PROFILE_UPDATE_REQUEST,
  payload: obj
});
```

Saga  file is defined as follows.

```
function* updateUserProfile(action) {
  try {
    let data = action.payload;
    yield call(userProvider.updateUserProfile, data);

    // dispatch a success action to the store
    yield put({ type: types.USER_PROFILE_UPDATE_SUCCESS, data });
    yield put(push('/dashboard'));
    yield put(constants.successMsg(userProfileUpdateSuccess));

  } catch (error) {
    // dispatch a failure action to the store with the error
    yield put(constants.DEFAULT_ERROR_MSG);
  }
}

export function* watchUserProfileUpdateRequest() {
  yield takeLatest(types.USER_PROFILE_UPDATE_REQUEST, updateUserProfile);
}


export default function* userSaga() {
  yield all([
    watchUserProfileRequest(),
    watchUserProfileUpdateRequest()
  ]);
}
```

But the code **yield put(push('/dashboard'))** is not redirecting on to the page.

Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: try putting your `put(push('/dashboard'))` line outside the try catch block

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I founded a solution myself

history.js

```
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';
const history = createHistory();
export default history;
```

Import history file into the saga

```
import history from '../../history';
```

Modify the watcher saga as follows.

```
function* updateUserProfile(action) {
  try {
    let data = action.payload;
    yield call(userProvider.updateUserProfile, data);

    // dispatch a success action to the store
    yield put({ type: types.USER_PROFILE_UPDATE_SUCCESS, data });
    yield call(forwardTo, '/dashboard');
    yield put(constants.successMsg(userProfileUpdateSuccess));

  } catch (error) {
    // dispatch a failure action to the store with the error
    yield put(constants.DEFAULT_ERROR_MSG);
  }
}
```

Now, you need to define the forwardTo function as follows.

```
function forwardTo(location) {
  history.push(location);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple example of what I've been doing, and the only way I found to make this work: (typescript with sagas)

MyCreateUserComponent.tsx

```
onHandleDelete() {
  const { push } = this.props.history

  const meta: ISagaActionMeta = {
    redirect: push,
    path: '/users'
  }

  // call Actioncreator
  DeleteUser(userId, meta)
}
```

actioncreator `DeleteUser` looks something like this:

```js
export const DeleteUser = (userId: number, meta: ISagaActionMeta): ISagaAction<number> => {
  return {
    type: Actions.user.USER_DELETE,
    payload: userId,
    meta
  }
}
```

on my saga... I do what its needed to delete the user (call the api, bla, bla) and then I call:

```
yield call(action.meta.redirect, action.meta.path)
```

The entire idea is just to pass the push function together with the rest of the data and use it when needed it.

Answer (score 0):

You need the history object to push to a different path.

1. If you can pass the history object in your action you can directly
   write **history.push('/dashboard')**.
2. You pass a callback function in
   the action from where the action was called and call that callback
   function with **yield put(callback())** so that you can redirect
   with the same command as mentioned in point 1.
3. window.location.href = 'dashboard';

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did and which works (The accepted answer just does not work for me) :

In your reducer, you add a boolean variable that will indicate if your request is a success. So you have something as follows :

```
case USER_PROFILE_UPDATE_SUCCESS:
    return {
      ...state,
      userProfileUpdated: true
    } 
  };
```

`userProfileUpdated` is obviously initiated to false.

Now, in your component, you do something as follows :

```
   render() {
      const { myReducer } = this.props;
        if (myReducer.userProfileUpdated) {
          return this.renderRedirect(ROUTES.DASHBOARD);
        } else {
          return this.renderUserProfileComponent();
        }
    }
```

Once your user profile has been successfully updated, your `userProfileUpdated` variable will switch to true, and your `MyProfile` component will re-render to load your `Redirect` component which you will have imported from `react-router-dom` with `/dashboard` as a pathname.